# ERROR/ActivityManager(98): Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut

Tags: android

i playing live video from api in my app. when i click play video then Progress dialog will come in between progress when i press back button 2 or 3 times of device then after some times it will give this error

```
ERROR/ActivityManager(98): Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut
```

so how i can handle this error plz give me solution.
Thnax in advace.

Answer (score 2):

This happens due to many reasons. I can't diagnose without your stack traces.

The most common reason for this error is when you are doing an CPU intensive task in a UI thread. Use threading or AsyncTask to delegate such CPU intensive work.

Answer (score 0):

Is any ANR thrown? If so go in `DDMS->File Explorer -> data/anr/traces.txt` and check at which point ANR occurred.

`keyDispatchingTimedOut` when you are doing heavy calculation on main thread. Move what you are doing in a new background thread (if possible)